# VSCode Intellisense selecting the wrong libraries for PlatformIO code

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, platformio

I'm using VSCode with the PlatformIO plugin and PlatformIO bazel integration (https://github.com/mum4k/platformio_rules) to write code for multiple different types of micro controllers (ATTiny84, ATTiny85, Arduino Nano, ESP32-S3). The code builds correctly as the bazel integration to PlatformIO selects the correct libraries, but as there are libraries with the same name made for different types of micro-controllers, IntelliSense will select one kind of at random and will mark a bunch of symbols as not defined or libraries not found (effectively, a lot of red squiggly marks)

As an example, I have some code that configures a timer for ATTiny85, and access registers like TCCR1 and OCR1A, which are correctly defined in Arduino.h for that micro-controller, but are not defined in any of the other 4 versions of the library available

Another example would be Arduino.h not defining Serial when built on ATTiny, but doing it when working with the Arduino Nano

The code I'm working on here is C++

Because of the fact that the whole project includes code for all of those micro-controllers (the project makes use of several different types of micros) I need to put the directories where all of those libraries are in for all of the micros in the include path, which is what I think is causing this problem. I have tried to fully qualify the path for the library that I'm using in my code, but that doesn't work because libraries included inside those libraries are not (and cannot be) fully qualified, so at some point this problem happens again, just one level of indirection down. Also, this code might end up being open source at some point, hence I cannot force my own absolute paths there

I would like either

- For VSCode IntelliSense to get information about the right libraries to include through either PlatformIO or Bazel (best solution)
- If that doesn't work, I'd like to have the option to change the include path on a per-directory basis. This would add additional directory structure on my project, and I'm still not 100% sure it would work, but would be a start

At this point I feel like my only option is to disable the red squiggly lines completely, but that looks like a sub-optimal solution